# Pubdate in feeds app interpreted as phone numbers in android

Tags: android, rss

So I've a very simple app that displays a bunch of RSS feeds from different sites in a listview. What is concerning me is that when I pull up the publishing dates from the sites the emulator and my phone both interpret it as phone numbers (although I am using them as strings). Just wondering if android handles all the numbers as phone numbers by default and if so then how should I make it behave?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Turn autoLink off for that TextView. If you need it for web, email and/or maps, set it specifically for those:

```
android:autoLink="web|email|map"
```